# Automatically resize the active window to maximum height

Tags: vimrc, vim-windows, autocmd

I know that it is possible: I googled it some time ago, but now I can't find the solution.

What do I need add to `.vimrc` to resize my current active window in full height automatically after window changing?

Comment: I remember also watching a screen cast where the user would resize the inactive windows to 5 lines, to keep the context.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with an auto command, filtering the `WinEnter` event:

```
autocmd WinEnter * resize
```

`resize` without argument expand the height to max.

**Refs:**

- `:h resize`
- `:h autocmd-events`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean by window, this should do it.

```
set winheight=999
set winminheight=0
```

See

```
:help 'winheight'
:help 'winminheight'
```